# Get request -> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

I am trying to call a code behind method in my ASP.NET web forms project.

jQuery ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MainContent_minuteBooks').click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "MainView.aspx/GetPageTypes",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("--" + JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Code behind c# method

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetPageTypes()
{
       List<string> pages = new List<string>();
       string html = "";

       foreach(MinuteBookPage mbp in book)
       {
           if (!pages.Contains(mbp.Class)) { pages.Add(mbp.Class); };
       }

       foreach(string s in pages)
       {
           html += "<div class='page' style='border: solid 2px red'><p>" + s + "</p></div>";
       }
       Console.WriteLine(html);

       return html;

}
```

I keep getting the error callback on my ajax call displaying

> Request: [object Object]
>   Status: parsererror
>   Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

I've already tried changing the dataType to text/html, results in the same issue. I've worked with ajax calls a lot in NETCORE so i'm not sure why this isn't working

Comment: `dataType: "json"` says you are expecting the service to return JSON.  HTML is not JSON.  Remove that argument

Comment: That seems to have solved that issue, thank you. Just as an aside am i referencing the url properly? Doesn't seem to be actually going to my method.